# SQL Server not accepting alias name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, alias

Constructing a SQL Server query for the first time today, and was surprised to see that this alias didn't work:

```
SELECT
    INVOICE_INVOICE_NUMBER AS invno,
    INVOICE_INVOICE_SEQ AS lineno
FROM
    INVOICED
```

But this did:

```
SELECT
    INVOICE_INVOICE_NUMBER AS invoice,
    INVOICE_INVOICE_SEQ AS line
FROM
    INVOICED
```

Changing the alias name is no big deal - but it would be good to know why this particular alias didn't work and how I can prevent or be aware of any future keywords to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LineNo` is a reserved word. You can encase it in brackets to use it.

```
SELECT INVOICE_INVOICE_SEQ AS [lineno]
```

[Reserved words](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! That reserved words link was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question itself. Keywords change colour and you should be able to easily make that out, unless you are typing your SQL query in notepad. Ideally it is not a good practice to use keywords for aliases, but if you have to, wrap them in square brackets - [ ].

Typically, reserved words turn blue, functions turn pink and system objects turn green. Of course you do have the ability to change the font in SSMS (Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors)

Raj

Comment: Hi Raj thanks for your input. I'm using the SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio which doesn't provide syntax highlighting. Only ever having used MySQL before I'm not used to encountering reserved words :)